# Redirect Users based on IP Address | Apache / htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-headers, directoryindex

I'd like to redirect users to an */index/* area of the site if they don't have my IP address.

How do I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: you list php and .htaccess - those are wide subjects with wildly divergent methods of delivery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.45\.67\.[8-9]$ # your ip here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index/
RewriteRule .? /index/ [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
{
    header('Location: /index/');
}
```

You can specify an array that matches against allowed IPs.

```
if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')))
{
    header('Location: /index/');
}
```